# perforce -m attribute for clean not in the docs

Tags: perforce

I was reading the following [article](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/15131) which is basically covering the `-m` flag for faster operation. However, when I'm looking to the [docs](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v14.2/cmdref/p4_clean.html), the `-m` command is not listed. Thoughts?

Comment: The linked article explains in detail what the `-m` option does.  What are you soliciting thoughts on, or what question do you have?

Comment: I was wondering if this is an addon that is not supported by default, as it's not part of the docs. I will add more information to this question to elaborate.

Comment: The canonical source of truth for which server commands are supported is `p4 help` (which is built into the server directly and therefore guaranteed to be up to date with the version of the server you're running), and `-m` is listed there, at least on the version I've got installed.  Will post that as an answer.  Omissions in the web docs are something you should raise with Perforce technical support.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The `-m` flag is described in `p4 help clean` as follows:

```
        The -m flag used in conjunction with -e can be used to minimize
        costly digest computation on the client by checking file modification
        times before checking digests to determine if files have been
        modified outside of Perforce.
```

(You can probably ignore the part about `-e` since edited files are included by default anyway -- that note is just to let you know that if you're explicitly only checking for added/deleted files there's no benefit gained from modtimes.)

It's directly analogous to the equivalent option on `reconcile`.  (`clean` is essentially a synonym for `reconcile -w` so the two commands have very similar options.)